# Unable to find ansible-test binary or documentation

Tags: ansible-2.x

After installing ansible and referring to the documentation on [testing strategies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/test_strategies.html), [options for `ansible-test`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing/sanity/index.html), [the cli reference](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/command_line_tools.html), and [more dev documentation referencing use of `ansible-test`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/testing_sanity.html), I've noticed that the `ansible-test` command appears to be completely missing.

I googled around a bunch and found [a third-party tool](https://github.com/nylas/ansible-test) (also called `ansible-test`) that appeared to fit the bill, but after pulling it down, realised that it was a completely different thing, and not at all what I was after.

The only reference to an ansible-test binary I've been able to find in the project is in the [test/runner folder](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/test/runner) of [the ansible project](https://github.com/ansible/ansible), but there appears to be no documentation that I've been able to find referencing how this is supposed to fit in with the rest of the commands.

Is this a bug? Should that link be in the main binary folder? Or have I missed some crucial bit of documentation telling me to manually add the `ansible-test` binary to my path when (and only when) doing development?

I would assume that with the noticeable lack of useful search results on this topic, that either people aren't using `ansible-test` to do their testing, or there's something I missed.

Comment: Had you found an answer?

Comment: Haha, nope. No response anywhere.

Comment: ansible-test  is internal ansible development utility. so it`s normaly using for testing ansible itself, not your roles.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere? Re-reading the existing "Sanity Test" docs with that context in mind makes sense, but it's certainly not explicit on the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see `setup.py` module [does not import](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/setup.py#L295) following script because it's used for internal purposes as mentioned in comments.

In case you want to launch that when developing Ansible follow [these steps](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html#environment-setup) and `ansible-test` executable will become available.

In case you want just similar functionality you can use either/both [ansible-lint](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-lint) and [molecule](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)